# Issue Submitting Dynamic Form After Deleting Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-core, razor

I have a form that I am building with a table, I want to be able to add or delete rows to this form and submit.

Here is a js.fiddle for my form

https://jsfiddle.net/oyvk1whx/

```
<form asp-controller="Institution" asp-action="AccountCategoryFees" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input asp-for="AccountCategoryId" type="hidden"/>

    <table class="table table-responsive" id="feeTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Description</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Price</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Delete</strong></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Fees.Count; j++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="Fees[j].Description" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span style="position: absolute; margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 8px;">$</span><input asp-for="Fees[j].Price" type="number" min="0.00" step="0.0001" max="2500" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="deleteButton btn btn-md btn-danger" value="Delete">
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" style="color:gray" value="Add Fee" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <div class="modal-footer" style="padding:0px;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn bg-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>


<script>
        var feeTypes = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model.Fees));
</script>

<script>
        var counter = @Model.Fees.Count;

        $('#feeTable').on("click", "#addrow", function () {

            var cols = "<tr>";
            cols += '<td><input id="Fees_' + counter + '__Description" name="Fees[' + counter + '].Description"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><span style="position: absolute; margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 8px;">$</span><input id="Fees_' + counter + '__Price" name="Fees[' + counter + '].Price" type="number" min="0.00" step="0.0001" max="2500" value="0" class="form-control"/></td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="button" class="deleteButton btn btn-md btn-danger" value="Delete"></td>';
            cols += '</tr>';

            $("#feeTable").append(cols);
            counter++;
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function (event) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        });
</script>
```

The script works fine for adding new rows and deleting rows. The issue is when I delete a row the form no longer submits correctly, all rows after the deleted one are ignored.

I believe this is because of the disconnect in the ids, since there is a gap the model binder cannot parse it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe this is because of the disconnect in the ids, since there is a gap the model binder cannot parse it

I would suggest to avoid square brackets in names and/or ids if possible and to solve your issue on your server side. In any case, if you need to rearrange IDs and NAMEs attributes you can simply cycle on each table row (because on server side you will handle only names, you can rearrange only these) :

```
$('#feeTable tr:has(input.deleteButton)').each(function(rIdx, row) {
    $(row).find('[id^=Fees_]').each(function(cIdx, col) {
        // col.id = col.id.replace(/\d+/, rIdx);
        col.name = col.name.replace(/\d+/, rIdx);
    });
 })
```

```js
var counter = 0;

$('#feeTable').on("click", "#addrow", function () {

    var cols = "<tr>";
    cols += '<td><input id="Fees_' + counter + '__Description" name="Fees[' + counter + '].Description"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><span style="position: absolute; margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 8px;">$</span><input id="Fees_' + counter + '__Price" name="Fees[' + counter + '].Price" type="number" min="0.00" step="0.0001" max="2500" value="0" class="form-control"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="deleteButton btn btn-md btn-danger" value="Delete"></td>';
    cols += '</tr>';

    $("#feeTable").append(cols);
    counter++;
});

$(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function (event) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    $('#feeTable tr:has(input.deleteButton)').each(function(rIdx, row) {
        $(row).find('[id^=Fees_]').each(function(cIdx, col) {
            // col.id = col.id.replace(/\d+/, rIdx);
            col.name = col.name.replace(/\d+/, rIdx);
        });
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-responsive" id="feeTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Description</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Price</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Delete</strong></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" style="color:gray" value="Add Fee" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<button type="submit" class="btn bg-primary">Save</button>
```

Comment: Works great thanks, I am a .Net developer and rely on built in model binding so I normally just use the bracket notation. If there is a better way to do so I am open for suggestions, but thanks again for the answer.